# Can QGIS load filtered layers on open from geopackage file?

Tags: qgis, layers, filter, geopackage

I have some external processing (FME from SAFE software) which generates a geopackage file with a set of tables.

Is it possible to load a set of filtered tables from a geopackage file when opening the project file?

More to the point I would like to add all tables named tbl_asset_* to a designated group when I open the QGIS project.

I am using QGIS 3.8.